# StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException

Tags: redis, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to use Redis as a cache for blacklisting JWTs, to implement logout with JWT.
I have downloaded redis on my windows 10 machine and run `"redis-server.exe"` and it says :

````
   [6112] 28 Nov 16:28:51.791 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.504 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 6112
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

[6112] 28 Nov 16:28:51.798 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.504
[6112] 28 Nov 16:28:51.799 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
[6112] 28 Nov 16:28:51.800 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379

     Redis 3.0.504 (00000000/0) 64 bit
    
        Running in standalone mode
    
     The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
````

which indicates that it is working correctly.

I'm using .NetCore 3.1 , and I have `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` v2.2.0 Nuget package installed.

in my `startup.cs` I added

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(r =>
            {
                r.Configuration = Configuration["Redis:ConnectionString"];
            });
```

and in my `appsettings.json` I have

```
 "Redis": {
    "ConnectionString": "localhsot"
  }
```

but at any request I'm sending I'm getting the following exception :

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(String configuration, TextWriter log) in c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 801
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.GetAndRefreshAsync(String key, Boolean getData, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.GetAsync(String key, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.DistributedCacheExtensions.GetStringAsync(IDistributedCache cache, String key, CancellationToken token)
```

what I'm I doing wrong? why am I getting this exception??
btw I was following this tutorial on [cancelling JWTs](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2018/04/25/canceling-jwt-tokens-in-net-core/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I'm saying this, but it turned out that the problem that caused this exception that drove me crazy was in the connection string.
instead of `"localhost"`, I typed `"localhsot"`. once I fixed it, everything worked as expected.